# Installing Less.css Client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, less

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/less.js"></script>
</head>
```

I get an error that it needs to be http:// instead of file://.  So does this mean I have to install apache and/or node?

Are there any links to documentation?  The less.css website isn't explicit enough for me.

Comment: Using LESS in the browser is fine for development, but **please** don't do it on your production site.

Comment: You don't need to use apache/node, you could try [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/), which is much lighter and simpler